# Why do controls synch values when they share a DataTable?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datatable, .net-3.5

So I have two `ComboBox`es that I bound to a simple `DataTable` (yes/no).

```
Dim tempTable As New DataTable()
tempTable.Columns.Add("value", GetType(Boolean))
tempTable.Columns.Add("displayValue", GetType(String))
tempTable.Rows.Add(True, "YES")
tempTable.Rows.Add(False, "NO")

comboBox1.DataSource = tempTable
comboBox1.ValueMember = "value"
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayValue"

comboBox2.DataSource = tempTable
comboBox2.ValueMember = "value"
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "DisplayValue"
```

For some reason, whenever I changed the value of one control the other would flip the same way.  Yet when I changed the line to `comboBox2.DataSource = tempTable.Copy()` this problem disappeared.

And when I changed the `.DataSource` lines to:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource() With {.DataSource = tempTable}
comboBox2.DataSource = New BindingSource() With {.DataSource = tempTable}
```

The problem goes away as well.  So I guess there is some sort of pooling of `BindingSources` that goes on?

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Binding sources have a position property and a PositionChanged event.  When the position changes the other controls receive that update and update accordingly.  By using different sources, your positions are independent of each other.

Comment: As @LarsTech says, your second example creates 2 independent binding sources. The 2nd combobox has no knowledge of the current position in first Combobox.

Comment: But why do they end up using the same `BindingSource` in the first instance?  There must be something in the code that deliberately gives the same `BindingSource` for the same objects, no?